# Python, using dictionaries and sets to keep track of all occurences of a word

Tags: python

I am trying to solve [this](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/word-order/problem) problem:

> You are given n words. Some words may repeat. For each word, output its
> number of occurrences. The output order should correspond with the
> input order of appearance of the word. See the sample input/output for
> clarification.
>
> Note: Each input line ends with a "\n" character.
>
> Input Format
>
> The first line contains the integer, n .
>
> The next n lines each contain a
> word.
>
> Output Format
>
> Output 2 lines. On the first line, output the number of distinct words
> from the input. On the second line, output the number of occurrences
> for each distinct word according to their appearance in the input.

I have implemented a solution like this,

```
# Enter your code here. Read input from STDIN. Print output to STDOUT

n  = int(input())

mySet = set()
myDict = {}

for i in range(n):
    inp = input()[:-1]
    if inp not in mySet:
        mySet.add(inp)
        myDict[inp] = 1
    else:
        myDict[inp] += 1

print(len(mySet))
# print(' '.join(list(map(str, myDict.values()))))
print(*myDict.values())
```

My strategy is as follows:

If the word is not in **mySet**, add it to the set and create a value-key pair on **myDict** with word as key and 1 as value.

If the word is in the set already, then increment the value of that word in the dictionary.

However, half of the test cases are successfull, but the rest are "Wrong Answer". So, I wonder, can anybody point out what do I miss to add to this code?

Comment: Why are you removing the last character from the input? if you might have new line character use `strip()`. And you don't need the set, just check the dictionary directly.

Comment: @Guy, it was to remove '\n' char, I knew it was unnecessary to remove it for my purpose. I have changed it when you told so, and now it passed all test cases. I believe, they did not put a newline at the end of some of the words on some test cases, despite they say each word will end with a '\n'. Which is not nice. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @Guy, using .strip() is a softer coding style, thanks for it also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your mistake is in `inp = input()[:-1]`. The `[:-1]` cuts off the word's last character. I guess you're trying to remove the newline character, but `input()` is already "[stripping a trailing newline](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input)". Demo:

```
>>> [input() for _ in range(2)]
foo
bar
['foo', 'bar']
```

Simpler solution, btw:

```
from collections import Counter

ctr = Counter(input() for _ in range(int(input())))
print(len(ctr))
print(*ctr.values())
```

And for fun a tricky version of that (also gets accepted):

```
from collections import Counter

ctr = Counter(map(input, [''] * int(input())))
print(len(ctr))
print(*ctr.values())
```

Another one:

```
from collections import Counter
import sys

next(sys.stdin)
ctr = Counter(map(str.strip, sys.stdin))
print(len(ctr))
print(*ctr.values())
```

This one reads the whole lines, so here the strings *do* include the newline character. That wouldn't matter if *all* lines had it, but no, HackerRank commits the cardinal sin of not ending the last line with a newline. So I `strip` them off every line. Sigh.

Comment: I did not know input() gets rid of the character '\n'. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In the problem, you don't need to use the `set` property and the way you are using input ie input()[::-1] is wrong as it is reversing the input which you have entered, ie for the input `abc` it is storing it as `cba`.

now to solve problem, as OP has figured out to take unique item use set, and to get the frequency of each word use dictionary. but using set is costly operation and dictionary can be used to get the unique word as it store unique keys which can be used to get the unique elments, and to get the frequency use the same operation as you are doing.

instead of adding key, value in dictionary by `dict[key]=value` better to update the current dictionary with inbuild method ie `dict1.update(dict2)` where `dict1` is orignal dictionary and `dict2` is new dictionary with key and value , `dict2={key:value}`, by this way you will keep the order of the element in dict.

to get the len of unique word , len of dictionary work ie `len(dic)` and to get the frequency of each word values need to printed ie `print(*dic.values())`

```
n = int(input())
dic  = {}

for _ in range(n):
  w = input()
  if w in dic.keys():
    dic[w]+=1
  else:
    dic.update({w:1})

print(len(dic.keys()))
print(*dic.values())
```

Comment: I tried it with "w in dic" and it worked, is dic.keys() necessary?

Comment: not necessary, it work same way, `if word in dic` and `if word in dic.keys()` work  same and check only the keys. just added keys to have more clear idea where it is checking the word

Comment: Can you please add an explanation!?

Answer (score 0):

```
n=int(input())
word_list=[]
for i in range(n):
    word_list.append(input())
    
New_word_list=[]
for element in word_list:
    if element in New_word_list:
        New_word_list=New_word_list    
    else:
        New_word_list.append(element)

print(len(New_word_list))
for element in New_word_list:
    print(word_list.count(element), end=" ")
```

Input:

```
10
cat
dog
dog
rabbit
cat
pig
horse
pig
pig
goat
```

Results:

```
6
2 2 1 3 1 1
```

Comment: Code only answers without any explanation are rarely helpful, and even if the code “should be self explanatory” adding explanation ensures _everyone_ can understand. Please consider updating your answer to not only include corrected or improved code, but also an explanation of _how_ and _why_ the implementation works. From [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer): "Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better."